# Django: Saving to DB from form example

Tags: python, django, django-forms

It seems I had difficulty finding a good source/tutorial about saving data to the DB from a form. And as it progresses, I am slowly getting lost. I am new to Django, and please guide me. I am getting error

> local variable 'store' referenced before assignment

Here are my relevant codes,

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Store(models.Model):
    store_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.store_name

class Feedback(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    date = models.DateTimeField("comment_date")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username
```

**views.py**

```
def add(request, store_name):
    if request.method == "POST":
        store = Store.objects.get(store_name=store_name)
        saved_username = request.POST.get("username", "")
        saved_feedback = request.POST.get("feedback", "")
        feedback = Feedback(username=saved_username, comment=saved_feedback, date=timezone.now())
        feedback.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("view", args=(store.id,)))
```

**addfeedback.html**(the one that calls add in views.py)

```
<html>
<head><title>Add Feedback</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={{ STATIC_URL }}styles.css>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="form">
    <form action="{% url add store.store_name %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="username" size="20"><br />
        <textarea name="feedback" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 2 years later and I have this issue as well

Comment: 2 years later and I forgot what the hell did I just asked.

Answer (score 2):

Use `django.forms` for the job. Don't put data straight from `POST` to db. See the related [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/).

```
local variable 'store' referenced before assignment
```

The error is obvious – you're referencing `store` even if the request isn't `POST`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pretty good [tutorial on ModelForms](http://www.peachybits.com/2011/09/django-1-3-form-api-modelform-example/). Although it's for Django 1.3, so it's slowly becoming obsolete.

You should only receive the  `local variable 'store' referenced before assignment` error when you access the form submission url directly. If a form has been posted to the url, store should be assigned.

You are trying to create a form based on a model, so I'll explain how you could use a ModelForm.

Your feedback model has a DateTimeField and you are storing the timestamp of when the feedback was submitted. You can automate this by setting `auto_now_add` to true

```
date = models.DateTimeField("comment_date", auto_now_add=True)
```

Then create a **forms.py** in your app folder with the following

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from your_app.models import Feedback
...
class FeedbackForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Feedback
        exclude = ('store',)
```

Your views.py should contain one function that displays and processes the submitted form

```
from your_app.forms import FeedbackForm
... 
def add(request, store_name):
    form = FeedbackForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        feedback = form.save(commit=False)
        store = Store.objects.get(store_name=store_name)
        feedback.store = store
        feedback.save()
```

Comment: When I tried to runserver, I got this "unexpected keyword argument auto_add_now"

Comment: Sorry I got it backward, it's `auto_now_add`

Comment: I just transfered store = Store.objects.get(store_name=store_name) this line to the top. And everything went fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue loading saving data into my database. This is how I solved it.

1. Create a form for you models
2. Create a view to process
3. Render your form Process the form by following the sample code below :

```
def add(request):
    form = feedback_models_form()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = feedback_models_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
          form_instance =  form.save(commit =  False)
          form_instance.store = Store.objects.get(store ="specific_store")
          form_instance.save()
          return ('/')
        else:
            pass
```