# Django: Submitting a form to a Database, suggested turorials?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have been reading and doing Django Tutorials for a while now. I am looking to build a relatively simple Survey facility for an experiment I am running.

However almost all of the form tutorials I have looked at relate to submitting a form to an email address e.g.

- [DjangoBook Chapter 7](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter07.html)
- [Working with Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/)

There are some [old SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13678979/django-saving-to-db-from-form-example) on this topic as well but the resources are either not complete or out of date.

I am looking to store the users feedback in the SQLite database. Can anyone recommend any resources for this? I understand that the methodology is similar but  there seems to be much less information about it.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "submitting a form to an email address" but both of those links show you exactly how to submit a form and save the data. However, the Django Book is generally out of date and should not be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) does exactly what you requested. In the [part 4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial04/) it's explained how to create a form and save the voting resuts to the database.